Data Migration Assistant does not show the results of the assessment
I'm planning a migration of some SQL Server Databases to Azure
I installed the Data Migration Assistant in one of the servers in order to start an assessment to gather all the compatibiliy issues of 2017 version to 2022 target version
But after connected to the SQL Instance, select the databases and start the assessment,  just "running" for hours without any result and output.
I know that the tool is deprecated but I only want the compatibily issues ( I did the same months ago and worked), the migration of the database will be with dbatools in order to automate the proccess due to the number of database to migrate is high.
My user is sysadmin so is not a permission problem.
Best regards

"I'm planning a migration of some SQL Server Databases to Azure" - To a VM in Azure, Azure SQL Database, or Azure Managed Instance?

Target should be Azure SQL Server IAAS
After some research seems that the problem is exporting the BACPAC
I'm just trying to get the compatibility issues, not the real migration.
First was a problem with timeout but now the error message seems that is the source of the data the problem. I will try to solve first those errors and then try again with the export of BACPAC

How big is the database? is DMA working on an AdventureWorks?
